# Find object in array of objects with same id

Tags: dojo

I have created classes

```
dojo.declare("UNIT",null,{
   _id:'',
   constructor:function(i){

       this._id=i;

   });
```

and

```
dojo.declare("ELEMENT", null, {
_id:'',
_unit_id:'',
constructor:function(u,i){
       this._unit_id=u;
       this._id=i;

   });
```

I have array of Units and I want find one which have id like my element._unit_id. Hot to do this with Dojo ? I was looking in documentation examples but there is dojo.filter by I cannot pass argument . Can anybody help ?

Comment: when are you going to start reading the docs on Dojo instead of asking an endless sequence of elementary questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dojo.filter.E.g:

```
 var units = [{
                id: 1,
                name: "aaaa"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "bbbb"
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                name: "cccc"
            },
            {
                id: "3",
                name: "dddd"
            }];

var currentElementId = 2;

var filteredArr = dojo.filter(units, function(item) {
            return item.id==currentElementId;
  });
          // do something with filtered array
}
```

[Test page for you](http://pastehtml.com/view/1drxveg.html)